# Ajax to refresh mutpliple parts of View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need an advice on using AJAX. I am designing a View that is to show tabulated data in the main (upper) part. Each row will be with a link `Select` which will refresh / fill two div containers with data corresponding to which link `Select` was clicked.

I know I could use `$.load()` or `$.get()` helpers of jQuery with `$('#select')` to trigger the async request Ajax. `$.get()` has an overloaded version to send an Object routesVlue to a controller. I think I need a JavaScript function for this. There's one thing I don't know how to sort out, probably easy to do. I need to somehow distinguish between all `Select` links so that they can execute the same JavaScript function but requesting different data. I hope it makes sense. The value that is provide this distinction is ID.

So I will have 20 select links and each of them should execute the function, send request based on different ID, get data back as HTML, JSON etc. and then refresh div containers with corresponding data.

I don't know if I should use PartialViews or JSON or PartialViews in one PartialView!

How can I sort it.

PS> I think I can use `@Html.ActionLink(0` to avoid hardcoded strings in AJAX.

---

EDIT:
Let's say I have data:

```
Number  Start       End         Target          Usage       
A0000   24/11/2014  27/11/2014  Non-commercial  null            Select
A0000   02/05/2013  29/05/2013  Academic        Student00       Select
A0000   28/12/2013  17/02/2014  Non-commercial  Student00       Select
A0000   16/04/2014  27/01/2014  Non-commercial  null            Select
A0000   15/02/2014  14/01/2014  Academic        Student00       Select
A0000   06/08/2014  14/02/2014  Academic        null            Select
A0000   08/11/2014  04/03/2014  Non-commercial  null            Select
A0000   26/05/2014  13/04/2014  Academic        Student00       Select
```

The last column contains links which populate two other `div` containers. When I click on `Select` I want to get details of `StudentXX` in one container, let's say `div1` and all modules assigned in `div2`. If I had one partial view to fill, I'd use `@Ajax.ActionLink("Select", "Details", "Students", <AJax options>, new { StudentID = m.ID })` etc. Because I want Ajax to do two operations simultaneously, I am afraid I need to make my own function in JavaScript:

```
function populateDivs(StudentID) {
   $('#select').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url1 = ('/Students/Details?ID=').concat(StudentID);
      var url2 = ('/ModuleJunction/List?ID=').concat(StudentID);
      $.get(url1, function(data) {
         $('#div1').html(data);
      });
      $.get(url2, function(data) {
         $('#div2').html(data);
      });
   });
}
```

I can't make it work. How to set `Select`s to invoke `populateDivs(StudentID)` with different parameters. On the other hand, `jQuery` is unobtrusive which I would prefer to use. I could name each `Select` link with corresponding `StudentID`, 'Student1','Student5', etc. Then in jQuery, `$('#Student1').click()` would handle the click event but if I have 20 links, I would need to make 20 functions. There must be something to solve it.

---

EDIT2:

```
<tr>
    <th>App. No.</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th>End</th>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Usage</th>
    <th>Link to paper version</th>
    <th>Info</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>APP0001</td>
    <td>01/06/2014</td>
    <td>08/06/2014</td>
    <td>Non-commercial</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="link-to-details" data-id="1">Select</span></td>
    <td><a href="/Applications/Edit?ApplicationID=1">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="/Applications/Delete?ApplicationID=1">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to post your view or some html so we can understand

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: @CerlinBoss, That PHP, not MVC!

Comment: it really doesn't matter

Comment: @ZikO, Can you add the html generated for one row of the table (so I can get the jquery selectors correct). And if both methods have the same parameter (`studentID`) is there any reason why they could not be combined (to return both the student details and their modules either as JSON or a partial view)?

Comment: @ZikO, The basic idea is to add the `studentID` to the elements data (e.g. `data-id="@item.ID"`) and then `$('.someClass').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Thanks for your comment! They probably could be combined! I have not reached that stage yet :p Frankly, I could not imagine that this way! .... I was testing something similar to what have suggested [here in the JSFiddle website](http://jsfiddle.net/ZikO/fd4t76xq/2/) (Hopefully you can read and execute the). It's working. Now, I would need to sort out ActionLink to add the attributes and implement Ajax in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.data()` to store and retrieve arbitrary data with an element. Assuming you model is `IEnumerable<Student>` and `Student` has property `StudentID`, then in your view

```
<table>
  ....
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        // other table cells
        <td><button type="button" class="details" data-id="@item.StudentID">Select</button><td>
        ...
      <tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="studentdetails"></div>
<div id="studentmodules"></div>
```

And in the script

```
$('.details').click(function() {
  var studentID = $(this).data('id'); // get the student id associated with the element
  $('#studentdetails').load('@Url.Action("Details", "Student")', { id: studentID });
  $('#studentmodules').load('@Url.Action("Modules", "Student")', { id: studentID });
});
```

Where you controller methods are

```
public PartialViewResult Details(int ID)
{
  var model = // get the student details based on ID
  return PartialView(model); 
}

public PartialViewResult Modules(int ID)
{
  var model = // get the student modules based on ID
  return PartialView(model); 
}
```

Note I have used a `button` rather that `a` element (your not navigating), but it can be easily styled to look like a link if that what you want.  Using jQuery `.load()` rather than `@Ajax.ActionLink()` means you can delete the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Big thanks :) It doesn't matter if it's button or link. I'll sort out presentationm styles and all these things later. Cheers!